# Ways to calculate number of years between two dates in Elixir

Tags: elixir

In order the calculate the number of years between two dates I've written the following code on iex:

```
>date1 = {{2016,3,21},{0,0,0}}
>date2= {{1983,12,27},{0,0,0}}
>:calendar.time_difference(date1,date2)
```

that returns the number of days between the two dates. Is there another way to calculate the difference?

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking for but this Q & A might help too: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69120/generating-all-valid-dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erlang date handling is pretty bad, so it is a good idea to use some external library to manage dates. For example [timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex).

Also José Valim [tweeted](https://twitter.com/josevalim/status/711870484422516738) that they pushed unified date/time libs for Elixir, so they might be ready for next Elixir version.